# How to change cursor from horizontal to vertical in R Studio?

Tags: r

I don't know what keys I pressed but my cursor seems to be an underscore(_) now, how do I change it back to a vertical(|)?

Comment: I am using Rstudio

Comment: Just hit the insert key